# Pygame : How to continously move character and view?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm not sure how to explain, but I'm trying to make game where player can walk on window and meet enemies etc.

I have code with one window. Like this:

```
window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 480))
```

And my character can move left, right and jump on this window, but when he gets to the corner he stops. So my question is how to make him move further and, for example, change background, meet another enemies etc. when he walks?
Do I have to make a class and call her when character touch corner maybe?
I hope you understand.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand when your character touch / is close enough to the border of the screen and then take appropriate action.
In a game I'm writing for fun, the class representing the main character has a method to check when the character is inside a surface `sface`. I copy-paste its skeleton here to show an example:

```
def insidesurf(self, sface):
    if sface.get_rect().contains(self.rect):
        return None
    else:
        if self.rect.top < sface.get_rect().top:
            #the character is going out from the screen from the top-side
        elif self.rect.left < sface.get_rect().left:
            #the character is going out from the screen from the left-side
        elif self.rect.bottom > sface.get_rect().bottom:
            #the character is going out from the screen from the bottom-side
        elif self.rect.right > sface.get_rect().right:
            #the character is going out from the screen from the right-side
```

This method is called at each iteration of the main loop after the character is moved (after a key press). The argument `sface` is your `window`.
What to do exactly in the various `if` statements is up to you. In my case, it redraws the screen replacing the character at the opposite side of the screen. If the character is exiting from left side, it's redrawn at right side, to give the impression that the camera is showing the next room and the character is at the same position.
You may also wish to not pass your `window` but a smaller surface in order to scroll the scenario instead of redrawing it all.